# Super Efficient object unwrapping

Tags: javascript, json

I have a snapshot coming from Firebase that I want to turn into a JS class. I currently have a monster loop that is terrible in almost every way. Would anyone have an example of a better way to turn the raw json into this class?

My current method is very long (see section two). I would love to learn a fast more efficient method.

Class:

```
class SuggestedLocation {
  country_slug
  region_slug
  slug
  marker_type
  typeInType
  geometry
  properties
  type
  id
  constructor(country_slug, region_slug, slug, marker_type, typeInType, geometry, properties, type, id) {
    this.country_slug = country_slug
    this.region_slug = region_slug
    this.slug = slug
    this.marker_type = marker_type
    this.typeInType = typeInType
    this.geometry = geometry
    this.properties = properties
    this.type = type
    this.id = id
  }
}
```

Current unwrapping method:

```
static fromSnapshot(snapshot) {
let suggestedLocations = [new SuggestedLocation()]
if (snapshot.exists()) {
  const value = snapshot.val()
  const countrySlugs = Object.keys(value)
  for (const country_slug of countrySlugs) {
    const regionSlugs = Object.keys(value[country_slug])
    for (const region_slug of regionSlugs) {
      const slugs = Object.keys(value[country_slug][region_slug])
      for (const slug of slugs) {
        const markerTypes = Object.keys(value[country_slug][region_slug][slug])
        for (const markerType of markerTypes) {
          const accomAmenityTypes = Object.keys(value[country_slug][region_slug][slug][markerType])
          for (const accomAmenityType in accomAmenityTypes) {
            const typeInTypes = Object.keys(value[country_slug][region_slug][slug][markerType][accomAmenityType])
            for (const typeInType of typeInTypes) {
              const ids = Object.keys(value[country_slug][region_slug][slug][markerType][accomAmenityType][typeInType])
              for (const id in ids) {
                const geoJsonObject = value[country_slug][region_slug][slug][markerType][accomAmenityType][typeInType][id]
                const properties = geoJsonObject["properties"]
                const geometry = geoJsonObject["geometry"]
                const type = geoJsonObject["type"]
                suggestedLocations.push(new SuggestedLocation(country_slug, region_slug, slug, markerType, typeInType, geometry, properties, type, id))
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
return new SuggestedLocationsObject(suggestedLocations)
```

}

Example Json:

```
{
  "united-kingdom" : {
    "calderdale" : {
      "rossendale-way" : {
        "accommodations" : {
          "Campground" : {
            "zO3HxZVELbd" : {
              "geometry" : {
                "coordinates" : [ -2.1901328761018704, 53.65022995288969 ],
                "type" : "Point"
              },
              "properties" : {
                "marker-color" : "#6e875f",
                "marker-size" : "medium",
                "marker-symbol" : "lodging",
                "name" : "",
                "place_id" : "zO3HxZVELbd",
                "plus_code" : ""
              },
              "type" : "Feature"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If that snapshot has an unknown number of subobjects you're not going to get any more efficient than those loops. If there is literally 1 `SuggestedLocation` per snapshot you don't need the loops at all.

Comment: Tangentially related (to readability) I'm confused why you get object properties and iterate but still use a full "path" to each object's "inner" properties when you're already dealing directly with the object in question already.

Comment: What's the purpose of `[new SuggestedLocation()]`? All properties of that instance will be undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to drill down your snapshot data any way, but you could use `Object.entries` instead of `Object.keys`, so you get the corresponding value in one go.

Also you could use `map` and `flatMap` to produce the array of `SuggestedLocation` instances without explicit `push`.

If the multiple assignments to `this.*` bother you, then you could consider changing the constructor signature so it takes an object instead of the individual values. Then you can use `Object.assign` to transfer those values in one go.

Finally, I don't really get why you want the array of `SuggestedLocation` instances to have an initial element with all undefined properties (`[new SuggestedLocation()]`). The only reason I can think of is for the case where `snapshot.exists()` is false... then you would have an array with this one entry. But when there is data, why would you have this dummy entry included?

Here is the code that expresses the above ideas (in plain JavaScript - not TypeScript):

```js
class SuggestedLocationsObject extends Array {
  constructor(arr) {
    super();
    Object.assign(this, arr);
  }
}

class SuggestedLocation {
  constructor(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
}

function fromSnapshot(snapshot) {
    return new SuggestedLocationsObject(
      !snapshot.exists() 
      ? [new SuggestedLocation()] 
      : Object.entries(snapshot.val()).flatMap(([country_slug, regionSlugs]) =>
          Object.entries(regionSlugs).flatMap(([region_slug, slugs]) =>
            Object.entries(slugs).flatMap(([slug, markerTypes]) =>
              Object.entries(markerTypes).flatMap(([markerType, accomAmenityTypes]) =>
                Object.entries(accomAmenityTypes).flatMap(([accomAmenityType, typeInTypes]) =>
                  Object.entries(typeInTypes).flatMap(([typeInType, ids]) =>
                    Object.entries(ids).map(([id, {properties, geometry, type}]) =>
                      new SuggestedLocation({country_slug, region_slug, slug, markerType, typeInType, geometry, properties, type, id})
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
    );
}

let data = {
  "united-kingdom" : {
    "calderdale" : {
      "rossendale-way" : {
        "accommodations" : {
          "Campground" : {
            "zO3HxZVELbd" : {
              "geometry" : {
                "coordinates" : [ -2.1901328761018704, 53.65022995288969 ],
                "type" : "Point"
              },
              "properties" : {
                "marker-color" : "#6e875f",
                "marker-size" : "medium",
                "marker-symbol" : "lodging",
                "name" : "",
                "place_id" : "zO3HxZVELbd",
                "plus_code" : ""
              },
              "type" : "Feature"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

let snapshot = {
    exists() { return true },
    val() { return data }
}

let result = fromSnapshot(snapshot);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: No that's a fair point re the initial empty SuggestedLocation. That was just to make my life a little easier with the built-in autocomplete!